# Symfony2: debug controller variables

Tags: php, model-view-controller, debugging, symfony

How can I quickly acces and view variables that are used in the controller ? I use xdebug, but often it is overkill to see what is inside an object when passing trough the controller.

Comment: I need debugging, not profiling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the variables defined in current scope using [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) method and log it using `Monolog` library e.g

```
    $this->container->get('logger')->info('Local variables', get_defined_vars());
```

I would recommend installing [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) extension in Firefox because in dev mode `FirePHP` handler is automatically enabled so you can see the info messages in firebug console. For more info about logging checkout [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html) cookbook entry.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, and indeed I can log messages in my firebug console. But can I output complex object too ?

Comment: Third argument of the method expects an array. You can typecast the object to array. But you may not get good result for deep nested object.

Comment: Ok, this is the closest I will get to an anwser :) there is not yet a good way in symfony to display complex abjects like 'devel' for drupal